# Numerically integration with a an infinite upper limit and non-zero lower limit

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I have seen lots of quadrature formulas where we have definite limits or one of the limits is infinity and the other is zero. But what about the following case

$$f(x) = \int_a^\infty e^{\frac{x}{t}} dt$$

How would I integrate this numerically when there is a non-zero lower limit?

Comment: Whats the problem with not having $0$ as the lower bound? You can start your numerical integration at non-zero points, e.g. approximate $$\int_{1}^{2} x^2dx$$ using the trapezoid rule with one interval of length $1$:
$$(2-1)\bigg(\frac{2^2-1^2}{2}\bigg)$$

Comment: Yes but what about a non-zero lower bound with an upper limit of infinity?

Comment: Treat it the same way you would if the lower bound where zero.

Comment: Well if the lower bound was zero I would use Gauss Laguerre quadrature - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature - but it doesn't say how to to treat the case where the lower bound isn't zero. I haven't been able to find a quadrature rule for an upper limit of infinity and a non-zero lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, $$\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx - \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$$